# MySQL: query for dates of the week that something did not occur

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with an ID, a datetime that something occurred, and a description of what it was.

With that table, I've been able to query for the number of times that something occurs during that day of the week with the following:

```
mysql> select distinct(DATE(HEADER_DATE)) from emails_inbound where WEEKDAY(HEADER_DATE) = 6;
+---------------------+
| (DATE(HEADER_DATE)) |
+---------------------+
| 2014-09-21          |
| 2014-09-28          |
| 2014-10-05          |
+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I'd like to see is a count of the number of days of the week (Sundays, in this example) that nothing occured (no result returned for that day) starting since a particular day.

In other words, how many Sundays since 9/1/2014 contain zero results?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: distinct is not a function

Comment: I'm going to assume this was meant as a comment for my answer and not for the question. Thanks for the catch! I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just put together a temp table that will give you a row for each day in your desired date range, and then `LEFT JOIN` that against your main table and `GROUP BY` the weekday.

I do not have MySQL at my disposal and this seems to be difficult to do in SQLFiddle (mix schema & non-schema statements), but the following code should work as-is or with very minor tweaks. It is important to note that I assume that the **ID** column of your `emails_inbound` table is called **id**; if it is something else, change `e.id` to `e.whatever`.

```
drop temp table if exists t_tmp;

create temp table t_tmp (
 my_date date
) engine=memory;

declare v_startDate date;
declare v_endDate date;

set v_startDate = '10-1-2014'; -- YOUR START DATE
set v_endDate = '10-10-2014';  -- YOUR END DATE

while (v_startDate < v_endDate) do
  insert into t_tmp values (v_startDate);
  set v_startDate = v_startDate + interval 1 day;
end while;

select weekday(date(e.header_date)) as day_of_week, 
       count(e.id) as number_of_days_when_this_event_happened,
       sum(case when e.id is not null then 0 else 1 end) as number_of_days_when_this_event_did_not_happen
from t_tmp x
    left join emails_inbound e on date(e.header_date) = x.my_date
group by weekday(date(e.header_date))

drop temp table t_tmp;
```